# AsyncTask onPostExecute never called

Tags: java, android, networking, android-asynctask

I need to create an AsyncTask class that return me String[], the String[] returned will be used to create a list so I was thinking to create ListActivity inside the AsyncTask class but onPostExecute method doesn't work, it is never called. My code :

```
public class AsyncReadPrices extends AsyncTask<Object, String[], String[]>{
static String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
static String ConfPath = new String();

    protected String[] doInBackground(Object... params){
        String[] menus = new String [(int) params[1]];
        try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url+params[0]).openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            for (int k = 0; k < (int)params[1]; k++) {
                menus[k] = line;
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            Log.i("check 1","");
            return menus;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("check 2","");
        return menus;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String[] menu) {
    Log.i("It works!","");
    new ListActivity(){
        @Override
        public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
            Log.i("string", menu[0] );
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, menu));
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Does `doInBackground()` get called? Does it crash. What else does/doesn't happen?

Comment: AsyncTask class is called, doInBackground works but onPostExecute method isn't called and I don't know why

Comment: Not sure about `new ListActivity()` but that's not the correct way to create an Activity. Does this log get called, `Log.i("It works!","");`?

Comment: No, Log.i("It works!",""); is never called, same of the method

Comment: `new ListActivity(){` what do you expect this to do?

Comment: Set a breakpoint there and see if it hits that line. I'm not sure if you understand how the logging works.

Comment: I used Log.i("It works!",""); to check if code was executed and it doesn't work infact I don't see "It works!" in my logcat

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using `ListActivity()` inside the `onPostExecute()` method. You should either be updating the `Adapter` or `ArrayList` with the values returned and then using the same `ArrayList` to populate your list.

Please try using this code:-

```
 @Override 
 protected void onPostExecute(final String[] menu) {


    itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter( 
                YourActivity.this, data);
    listView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter); 
}
```

// listView should be earlier be initialized inside your activity class

// itemListAdapter if you are using a custom adapter, else directly use

Comment: The problem is before ListActivity, onPostExecute isn't running, the method is ignored